# unzip returns non-zero code 2 on Android NDK zip (tested multiple versions)

Tags: linux, docker, android-ndk, unzip

I'm running the simple docker commands (`ubuntu:bionic`) to download Android NDK and unzip it:

```
ENV ANDROID_NDK_VERSION r21d
ENV ANDROID_NDK_URL http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.zip
RUN curl -L "${ANDROID_NDK_URL}" -o android-ndk-${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.zip
RUN unzip android-ndk-${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.zip -d ${SDK_HOME}
```

But I always get (even if I prune everything and start again):

```
  creating: /opt/android-ndk-r21d/wrap.sh/
  inflating: /opt/android-ndk-r21d/wrap.sh/asan.sh  
The command '/bin/sh -c unzip android-ndk-${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.zip -d ${SDK_HOME}' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

`/opt/android-ndk-r21d/wrap.sh/asan.sh` is the last thing to be unzipped. On `r20`, it's `inflating: /opt/android-ndk-r20/ndk-stack`, then I get the same error.

Running unzip with `-v` as suggested below gives an weird output:

```
   16704  Defl:X     3281  80% 2019-05-22 12:47 80a0acc7  android-ndk-r20/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c
     577  Defl:X      371  36% 2019-05-22 12:47 e63c146e  android-ndk-r20/sources/android/native_app_glue/NOTICE
     439  Defl:X      282  36% 2019-05-22 12:47 8fc9fc18  android-ndk-r20/sources/android/native_app_glue/Android.mk
       0  Stored        0   0% 2019-05-22 12:47 00000000  android-ndk-r20/sources/android/renderscript/
     577  Defl:X      371  36% 2019-05-22 12:47 e63c146e  android-ndk-r20/sources/android/renderscript/NOTICE
     813  Defl:X      234  71% 2019-05-22 12:47 bfbf4628  android-ndk-r20/sources/android/renderscript/Android.mk
    2172  Defl:X     1117  49% 2019-05-22 12:47 43b8cf66  android-ndk-r20/CHANGELOG.md
      92  Defl:X       86   7% 2019-05-22 12:50 250f0ae3  android-ndk-r20/ndk-stack
--------          -------  ---                            -------
3049400190         854740668  72%                            18484 files
```

which executes instantly (no delay for unzipping) and then the image continues to build, but when it finishes there's nothing on the unzipped destination.

I tried downloading sdk `r21c`, `r21b` thinking that maybe it was a problem with the zip archive, but it wasn't. Container is ubuntu:bionic.

Comment: I can confirm that `inflating: /opt/android-ndk-r21d/wrap.sh/asan.sh` should be the last thing that happens during unzip. Maybe the problem is that you choose `/opt` as target. Consider unzipping to a *home* directory. You can move the whole tree wherever you want later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl` was downloading corrupt files the majority of the time. Compred using `sha1` from android website and from the downloaded file.

By moving to `wget` it worked...

Comment: That's kinda weird.  Usually `curl` > `wget`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) exit code 2 is a generic error.

> 2
> a generic error in the zipfile format was detected. Processing may
> have completed successfully anyway; some broken zipfiles created by
> other archivers have simple work-arounds.

Run `unzip` with option `-v` to see the diagnostic output, which should help debug this issue.

Edit: I'm not exactly sure what's going on with unzip, but the following works for me:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ENV SDK_HOME /var/ndk
ENV ANDROID_NDK_VERSION r21d
ENV ANDROID_NDK_URL http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.zip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl unzip && apt-get clean && \
    curl -L "${ANDROID_NDK_URL}" -o android-ndk-${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.zip && \
    unzip -qq android-ndk-${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.zip -d ${SDK_HOME} && \
    rm -f android-ndk-${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.zip && \
    apt-get -y remove curl unzip && apt-get -y autoremove && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help! I discovered that `curl` was downloading the file wrong. It was corrupted the majority of the time. I used th SHA1 provided by android website and compared. Simply changing to wget worked...

Comment: Strange. Never experienced anything like that myself I'm glad you made it work though.